# Unable to copy txt file over to arraylist and into file

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I am attempting to add this large txt file into an array list then sort the data. Then put 15000 lines in various temp files. I am unable to put the data into each file. Here is my code:

```
package bigfilesorter2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bigfilesorter2 {

    public static final int NUM_LINES = 15000;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {



        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("Aesop_Shakespeare_Shelley_Twain.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        ArrayList<String> arraylist = readingfile(br);

        //System.out.println(arraylist);
        makingfiles(br, arraylist);

    }

    public static void makingfiles(BufferedReader br, ArrayList<String> arraylist) throws IOException {
        int start = 0;
        int end = 15000;

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            File file = new File("/Users/domlanza/desktop/testing/Filee"+i+".txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            for(;start <= end; start++){
                bw.write(arraylist.get(start));
                bw.newLine();
            }
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
            fw.close();
            start = end + 1;
            end += 15000;
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> readingfile(BufferedReader br) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        //Read in file

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("Aesop_Shakespeare_Shelley_Twain.txt"));
        int count = 0;
        ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (s.hasNext()) {
                count++;
                arraylist.add(s.nextLine());

            }




        //} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        Collections.sort(arraylist);
        //System.out.println(arraylist);
        return arraylist;
        }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. the commas were just the file being sorted..................

"it looks like your post is mostly code"

Comment: What exactly is the problem now?

Comment: @SuperMario48 *"I am unable to put the data into the file."*

Comment: My problem is I just want to only put 0-15000 lines of my arraylist in the first file then 15,001-30,000 in the second, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a list of sublists where each sublist holds 15000 lines. Given below is the complete code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class BigFileSorter {

    public static final int NUM_LINES = 15000;
    public static final int NUM_FILES = 20;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("file.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = readingfile(br);
        makingfiles(br, list);

    }

    public static void makingfiles(BufferedReader br, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list) throws IOException {
        if (list != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FILES; i++) {
                File file = new File("Filee" + i + ".txt");
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
                ArrayList<String> subList = list.get(i);
                for (String str : subList) {
                    fw.write(str + System.lineSeparator());
                }
                fw.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> readingfile(BufferedReader br)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> subList;
        String line;
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FILES; i++) {
                subList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int j = 0; j < NUM_LINES; j++) {
                    line = br.readLine();
                    if (line == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    subList.add(line);
                }
                Collections.sort(subList);
                list.add(subList);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt.

Comment: I'm assuming its giving a null pointer because there is nothing past 149034

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.binarySort(ComparableTimSort.java:262)
at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:207)
at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1315)
at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1509)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1749)
at java.base/java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:143)
at assignment11yatesbigfilersorter.bigfilesorter.readingfile(bigfilesorter.java:46)
at a11yatesbigfilersorter.bigfilesorter.main(bigfilesorter.java:18)

Comment: it creates all the files just the files are duplicates and files 0-4 have text but 5-19 do not

Comment: does the sort need to be moved somewhere else in the loop?

Comment: its just giving me three little files with none of the contents

Comment: I think the collections.sort method needs to be moved because each file is beginning with the same word

Comment: its only printing to the first 10 files

Comment: Thank for your help I really appreciate it and your time sir

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this as an inner for loop in your makefiles method.

```
// outside of the for loops
int start = 0;
int end = 15000;


// inner for loop
for(;start <= end; start++){
    bw.write(arraylist.get(start));
    bw.newline();
}
// end of outer for loop
start = end + 1;
end += 15000;
```

So complete method:

```
public static void makingfiles(BufferedReader br, ArrayList<String> arraylist) throws IOException {
    int start = 0;
    int end = 15000;

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        File file = new File("/Users/domlanza/desktop/testing/Filee"+i+".txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        for(;start <= end; start++){
            bw.write(arraylist.get(start));
            bw.newline();
        }
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
        fw.close()
        start = end + 1;
        end += 15000;
    }
}
```

Should work for what you asked in the comment, but you still have to change your read method so that it reads all the lines in one arraylist

Comment: That makes sense. The index is just out of bounds now

Comment: Inside the loop should I break when end is past 149034 (thats the length of the file)?